# Accessing static variable in spring annotations using spel

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

I have a value in annotation, for which I want to assign a static variable
I tried something like this

```
@Cacheable(value = "#com.test.App.VALUE")
public List someCachableMethod() { }
```

After trying this its still same Exception : field or Property cannot be  found or null

```
public class App {
    private static String MY_NAME = " XXXX";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
            Expression exp = parser.parseExpression("#MY_NAME)");
            String message = (String) exp.getValue();
            System.out.println("---------------->"+message);
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: And your problem is?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use the `T` operator:

```
"#{T(com.test.App).VALUE}"
```

but make the constant `public`.