# SpEL unable to access the instance variable

Tags: spring, spring-el

I am trying to make use of Spring Boot AutoConfigured `@EnableScheduling` to create a cron job. Job triggers perfectly fine if the `fixedRateString` is hardcoded. However it does not succeed if I try to make use of SpEL to supply the value.

> //Bean Instantiation in JavaConfig

```
@Bean
public AlertbotJob2 getAlertJob2() {
    AlertbotJob2 alertbotJob2 = new AlertbotJob2("alertId", "alertName", "alertSubject", "6000", true);
    return alertbotJob2;
}
```

> Bean Definition

```
public class AlertbotJob2 {

String alertId;
String alertName;
String alertSubject;
public String cronPattern;
boolean isActive;

public AlertbotJob2() {
}

public AlertbotJob2(String alertId, String alertName, String alertSubject, String cronPattern, boolean isActive) {
    super();
    this.alertId = alertId;
    this.alertName = alertName;
    this.alertSubject = alertSubject;
    this.cronPattern = cronPattern;
    this.isActive = isActive;
}

@Scheduled(initialDelay = 60000, fixedRateString = "#{this.cronPattern}")
public void doTheJob() {
    System.out.println("DoSomething");
}
```

}

> Exception is :: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'this' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public?

I am just trying to set the trigger values dynamically. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use SpEL like this.
Maybe the better approach is to define your cron pattern in some property like:

```
myapp.scheduler.cronPattern=...
```

And then use the following syntax:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${myapp.scheduler.cronPattern}")
public void doTheJob() {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `this` there.

You have to do it by bean name `@someBean.cronPattern`.

Comment: Well, I tried that approach but did not work well. As I am programmatic ally creating the beans after reading database configurations.

Need to figure out if **@someBean**.cronPattern can be created with prototype scope ..

Comment: No; there is no way for the SpEL expression to directly refer to the instance of the class in which the annotation resides.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: use the hardcoded pattern if its already known
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0/5 * * * MON-FRI")

Solution 2: If the pattern is available in some property
@Scheduled(cron = "${myapp.scheduler.cronPattern}")

Solution 3 : This approach does not use annotation. Instead the Beans are just implemented as runnables And then override the SchedulingConfigurer.configureTasks() to dynamically set the schedules using taskRegistrar.addCronTask(urRunnableJob, urCronPatternFromDB); . Cron pattern is stored in database table, initialize it as properties as below.

```
class AppConfig { 

    @Autowired
    ConfigurableEnvironment environment;

    private void initPropertiesMap() {
        environment.getPropertySources()
            .addLast(new MapPropertySource("myAppProperties", myAppProperties.getProperties())); // Prior DAO call required to read the configs from database
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        initPropertiesMap();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
   e.g @Value("#{T(com.someName.ClassName).cronPattern}")
```

I reference this [Accessing static variable in spring annotations using spel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31748894/accessing-static-variable-in-spring-annotations-using-spel)