# How to use constant in Spring custom annotation?

Tags: spring, aop

I'm trying to create a custom annotation in Spring (version: 6.0.4), that should be able to use a constant in its parameter, like the annotation @PreAuthorize.

## **How am I using the annotation @PreAuthorize ?**

application.properties:

```yaml
authorization.a=AUTH_A
authorization.b=AUTH_B
authorization.c=AUTH_C
```

```java
@Configuration("authorization")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "authorization")
public class AuthorizationProperties {

    public static String AUTH_A;
    public static String AUTH_B;
    public static String AUTH_C;

    private String a;
    private String b;
    private String c;

    public void setA(String a) {
        this.a = a;
        AuthorizationProperties.AUTH_A = a;
    }

    public void setB(String b) {
        this.b = b;
        AuthorizationProperties.AUTH_B = b;
    }
    public void setC(String c) {
        this.c = c;
        AuthorizationProperties.AUTH_C= c;
    }

}
```

```java
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority(@authorization.AUTH_A)")
```

The annotation @PreAuthorize knows what *@authorization.AUTH_A* is. (Actually, my IDE can make a link to the class).

## **What have I done so far ?**

I would like to do the same thing with my own custom annotation.

application.properties:

```yaml
action.CREATE=CREATE
action.UPDATE=UPDATE
action.DELETE=DELETE
```

```java
@Configuration("action")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "action")
public class ActionProperties {

    public static String CREATE;
    public static String UPDATE;
    public static String DELETE;

    private String create;
    private String update;
    private String delete;

    public void setCreate(String create) {
        this.create = create;
        ActionProperties.CREATE = create;
    }

    public void setUpdate(String update) {
        this.update = update;
        ActionProperties.UPDATE = update;
    }

    public void setDelete(String delete) {
        this.delete = delete;
        ActionProperties.DELETE = delete;
    }

}
```

My annotation look like this:

```java
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
@Documented
public @interface Audit {

    String action();

}
```

```java
 @Audit(action = "@action.CREATE")
```

The problem is that in my aspect, I received the string "@action.CREATE" and not "CREATE":

```java
    @Before(value = "@annotation(audit)")
    public void beforeAuditedMethod(JoinPoint joinPoint, Audit audit) {
        LOGGER.info("audit action: " + audit.action());
    }
```

What am I missing ? How is the annotation @PreAuthorize working and able to "interpret" it's parameter ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing static variable in spring annotations using spel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31748894/accessing-static-variable-in-spring-annotations-using-spel)

Comment: `public static String AUTH_A;` is not a constant, it is a class level variable. `public static final` would be a constant.

Comment: Well, technically it is a constant, not a variable. What you meant to say is that it is an instance field, not a static (class-level) field and as such, despite being final, not stored in the constant pool of its containing class. To the OP: Maybe you want to read the ["Java Annotation Attribute Value Restrictions"](https://www.baeldung.com/java-annotation-attribute-value-restrictions) Baeldung tutorial. You see, it is a JVM restriction and unrelated to AOP. But SpEL can be a good workaround when dealing with configuration values, referencing them from annotation values.